# Android unable to set images from gallery to ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I am using this library(https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect) for selecting images from gallery and to set the images to Imageviews.In the onActivityResult() I use `ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);` to get the paths of the selected images.But I couldn't set the set the images I selected to the ImageViews.

Code:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(AddOffers.this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                    //set limit on number of images that can be selected, default is 10
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 3);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
                ArrayList<Image> images =     data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
                offr_img1.setImageUri(images.get(0));
 }}
```

Comment: What is the value of 'images.get(0)' that you are getting ?

Comment: When I use the method it is underlined in red(Error)

Comment: This is the type (com.darsh.multipleimageselect.models.Image) of data in the arraylist images

Comment: Added an answer. Tell if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I saw is you are passing the full Image object but you are expected to pass a path to set the image.

In your code, try changing this -

```
offr_img1.setImageUri(images.get(0));
```

to

```
offr_img1.setImageUri(images.get(0).path);
```

Comment: There is no such method as path

Comment: Give me some minutes. Checking the exact method.

Comment: This is the Class. The constructor has a parameter called 'path' that gives the path of the Image. https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect/blob/master/multipleimageselect/src/main/java/com/darsh/multipleimageselect/models/Image.java

Comment: did you try my answer ? basically instead of passing the full object, pass the path of the image to set the image in setImageUri method. Check the example given by the author here - https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/darsh/example/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: offr_img1.setImageUri(images.get(0).path); This is proper syntax. @jobin

Comment: Or instead of using setImageUri to set the image, use any library like Picasso or Glide

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(AddOffers.this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                //set limit on number of images that can be selected, default is 10
                intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 3);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
            ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
             Uri uri=Uri.parse(images.get(0).path);
            offr_img1.setImageUri(uri);
    }}
```